# Flexbox on IOS scrolls differently

Tags: ios, css, mobile, scroll, flexbox

I noticed the scrolling functionality is different when using a flexbox based layout vs a `position: fixed` footer. The fixed footer is much smoother and shows a scrollbar. Flexbox isn't smooth at all, and does not show the scrollbar. I'd much prefer to use flexbox for my layout, but want the nicer scroll. Is there any way to achieve it with flexbox?

I'm testing on IOS 10 Iphone 7. Happens on both chrome and safari

[Flexbox example](http://codepen.io/bi11johnston/pen/ozrPOJ)

[Fixed footer example](http://codepen.io/bi11johnston/pen/rrAkEz)

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div id='main'>
            ...lots of content so it would scroll
        </div>
        <nav class="footer">footer</nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Flexbox method:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
}

#main {
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 0px;
}

.footer {
    height: 72px;
    min-height: 72px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Fixed footer method:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main {
    padding-bottom: 72px;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 72px;
    min-height: 72px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there's nothing to do with Flexbox.it's only the problem about overflow.so add this : `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` will work.